# How can I plot sin(t) with Modelica

Tags: openmodelica

I'm new using `open modelica`.  I need to plot a sin(t)?

```
sin= sin fuction
t = time
```

You can see this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model.

```
model SinModel
   Real x;
equation
   x = sin(time);
end SinModel;
```

Then simulate SinModel and plot x.